# Напечатать минор матрицы определитель которого наибольший

Tags: c++

В общем у меня есть матрица 4х4 и мне нужно напечатать минор матрицы определитель которого Наибольший. Пока я знаю как заполнить матрицу рандомно цифрами и найти ее определитель но проблемы в том, что я не знаю как найти все миноры матрицы. Кто-то может помочь с кодом?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n; cin >> n;
    int** matrix = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int [n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ищу  определитель формулой `d = d + (pow(-1 ,c) * mat[0][c] * det(n - 1 ,submat))`

Comment: За `pow(-1 ,c)` надо бить по рукам с малых лет...

Comment: лучше б с кодом помог

Comment: @GrandPa: лучше бы вы прислушались к совету

Comment: Щас "внезапно" выяснится, что под "всеми минорами матрицы" оказывается имеются в виду только *дополнительные* миноры элементов, т.е. миноры порядка `n-1`. А я разошелся с перечислением всех подмножеств...

Comment: @AnT Вообще-то, поскольку ничего не было сказано о порядке минора, например, я именно так задачу и воспринял :)

Comment: @Harry: Ну вообще-то математику тот факт, что "ничего не было сказано о порядке минора" говорит именно о том, что порядок может быть любым. Но, учитывая  `pow(-1 ,c)`, трудно предположить, что студентам на этом этапе обучения могли предложить задачу такого уровня сложности. (Я был бы приятно удивлен, но признаю, что надежды мало.)

Comment: @AnT Так это математику... :)

Answer (score 5):

Лобовое решение данной задачи пугает своей переборностью, но если решать задачу в лоб, т.е. через вычисление всех возможных миноров <sup>(1</sup>, то вам понадобится способ перечисления всех возможных квадратных подматриц. Минор определяется одинаковыми по мощности подмножествами строк и столбцов матрицы. Вот такие подмножества вам и надо генерировать, во всех возможных их вариантах.

Например, для каждого возможного подмножества строк мощности 1 надо сгенерировать все возможные подмножества столбцов мощности 1. Для каждого возможного подмножества строк мощности 2 надо сгенерировать все возможные подмножества столбцов мощности 2. И т.д. до мощности `n - 1` <sup>(2</sup>.

Задавать такие подмножества можно парой упорядоченных по возрастанию векторов целых чисел, т.е. наборами индексов строк и столбцов матрицы. Числа берутся из диапазона `[0, n)`, а размер вектора задает рассматриваемый в данный момент порядок минора `m`. Тогда функция, перечисляющая все возможные подмножества, может выглядеть, например, так

```
bool next_subset(std::vector<unsigned> &subset, unsigned n)
{
  unsigned overflow = n;
  auto it = subset.end();

  do
  {
    --it;
    if (++*it < overflow || it == subset.begin())
      break;

    --overflow;
  } while (true);

  assert(*it <= overflow);
  if (*it == overflow)
    return false;

  for (++it, ++overflow; it != subset.end(); ++it, ++overflow)
  {
    *it = *(it - 1) + 1;
    assert(*it < overflow);
  }

  return true;
}
```

В качестве самого первого подмножества используется вектор `{ 0, 1, ..., m-1 }`, а далее последовательные вызовы этой функции будут генерировать вам всевозможные подмножества длины `m`, пока функция не вернет `false`.

Таким образом, общая структура переборного алгоритма будет такой <sup>(2</sup>

```
int main()
{
  unsigned n = 0;
  std::cin >> n;
  // `n` - размер матрицы

  ...

  for (unsigned m = 1; m < n; ++m)
  { // `m` - порядок минора
    std::vector<unsigned> rows(m);
    std::iota(rows.begin(), rows.end(), 0);

    do
    {
      std::vector<unsigned> columns(m);
      std::iota(columns.begin(), columns.end(), 0);

      do
      {
        // А сюда вставляем вычисление определителя для минора
        // образованного строками из `rows` и столбцами из `columns`
        /*
        for (unsigned i : rows) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "- ";
        for (unsigned i : columns) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        */

      } while (next_subset(columns, n));
    } while (next_subset(rows, n));
  }
}
```

Я пока что вставил в "тело" алгоритма отладочную печать, которая продемонстрирует вам, какие генерируются наборы строк и столбцов минора.

А дальше - дело техники. Вам надо лишь модифицировать вашу функцию вычисления определителя так чтобы она работала не напрямую с исходной матрицей, а с "виртуальной" подматрицей, задаваемой индексными массивами `rows` и `columns`.

Или, если вам так больше нравится, вы можете явно формировать отдельную временную подматрицу из `rows` и `columns` и напускать на нее вашу готовую функцию вычисления определителя.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Минор - это по определению и есть определитель, т.е. "определитель минора" - это уже "масло масляное".

<sup>2)</sup> Диапазон порядков миноров и, соответственно, внешнего цикла будет зависеть от того, считаете ли вы минором определитель всей матрицы (минор порядка `n`).

---

**Лирическое отступление:** Остроумным "хакерским" способом перечисления всех подмножеств размера `m` для данного множества размера `n` является bit-twiddling техника, основанная на функции

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned u = x & -x;
  unsigned v = u + x;
  x = v  + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
  return x;
}
```

Эта функция перечисляет в порядке возрастания все двоичные числа, содержащие одно и то же количество единичных битов в своем представлении. Как бы мне ни хотелось, я, однако, не вижу необходимости притягивать за уши этот подход в решение данной задачи.

Хотя можно заметить, что на тех размерностях, на которых эту задачу имеет смысл решать перебором, перечисление разнообразных битовых подмножеств для построения подматриц можно выполнить просто как

```
for (unsigned rows = 1; rows < (1u << n) - 1; ++rows)
  for (unsigned columns = 1; columns < (1u << n) - 1; ++columns)
    if (count_bits(rows) == count_bits(columns)) 
    { // Одинаковое количество единичных битов
      // Считаем минор
    }
```